# Wordpress how to change a page URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, lms

Image of the website for which I want to change the URL:

[image]

I have a plugin called tutor LMS in WordPress and I customized a lot of things but the only thing which I am unable to customize is the URL, It is calling a template called `my-profile.php`.

Now I can successfully customize its all parts except the URL.

Is there any way so that I can change its URL

from:

```
websitename/dashboard/my-profile/
```

to

```
websitename/online-id-card/
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: In plugin/classes/utils.php at line 2454 you will find a function tutor_dashboard_pages where you see a filter of the menu items. You can try editing with that. I dont have currently time to install and do some testing. GL

Comment: No Its Not Working :(

Answer (score 0):

The Tutor LMS plugin has a "Permalink Settings" screen that lets you set the URL.

https://docs.themeum.com/tutor-lms/settings/permalink-settings/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your WordPress settings >> permalinks
You'll see the option to customise the url